# Can't access web service exposed by application deployed in vert.x from gwt application

Tags: web-services, gwt, vert.x

I have a REST web service exposed by application deployed in vert.x and I'm trying to access it from a GWT application. Some response is obtained, but with an empty body.

It gives the expected response when I access the service using http4e.

Is there any required configuration other than normal web service access code in GWT? Below given is the code for web service access:

```java
final RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
                RequestBuilder.POST, "https://localhost:80/login");
requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
requestBuilder.sendRequest("{\"userId\":\"" + username
                    + "\",\"password\":\""
                    + password + "\"}",
                    new RequestCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                                    Response response) {
                                System.out.println("response:"
                                        + response.getText());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Request request,
                                    Throwable exception) {
                                System.out.println("ex:"
                                        + exception.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
```

**EDIT:** I think there is some issue in the client side request. When the `sendRequest` function is called, `onResponseReceived` in the RequestCallback implementation gets invoked, with empty response. The POST request status is reported as **Aborted** when I analyzed using Firebug.

Comment: could you correct the typo at http4e ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that you turn to localhost, this is CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction) different ports mean different origins. [Modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/cors) forbid cross-domain *XMLHTTPRequest* by default. You should add *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header to server's respones. Read the [Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#syntax) section of the CORS specification for further information.

Comment: I think there is some issue in the client side request. When the `sendRequest` function is called, `onResponseReceived` in the RequestCallback implementation gets invoked, with empty response. Pls see the edit.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the way CORS works. You can see this by disabling CORS security in your user agent. If you use google chorme run it with option '--disable-web-security'.

Comment: Is there any issue in using `RequestBuilder` for **https** POSTing?